# MATLAB Calculate time given Aircraft trajectory

Tags: matlab, navigation

I'm trying to calculate the cumulative time of an aircraft trajectory given the following parameters:

```
Roll
Pitch
TrueHeading
HeadingRateofChange
XVelocity
YVelocity
ZVelocity
Latitude
Longitude
Altitude
```

The data file contains 10,000 points for each of the above parameters, representing the trajectory at each of those points.

So far, what I have done is calculate the radial velocity by squaring the velocity components, summing them, and taking the square root of that sum i.e:

```
RVelocity = sqrt(Vx.^2 + Vy.^s + Vz.^2) % 9999x1 column vector
```

Then I use the MATLAB distance function to calculate the arclength distance:

```
AL = distance(pt1,pt2,wgs84ellipsoid) % 9999x1 column vector
```

Finally, I divide AL by RVelocity:

```
Time = AL./RVelocity % 9999x1 column vector
```

After all this work, it seems like I get a really bogus answer... Can anyone recommend a better way to implement this?

Comment: Are you *totally sure*, you dont have the sampling time of the sampled data???

Comment: Yes. The data is simulated via another computer program which I do not have access to.

Comment: This is completely nonsense doing archeological engineering instead of not getting a simple number data by a phone call or an email. There are methods of course, but not contacting or investigating about the source of the data is not worth the effort.

Comment: Clearly the data comes from a DAQ, which ussualy takes data at a regular sampling data. It is possible of course, if you dont want to contact the people who own the computer, and apply parameter estimation for obtaining that value, but as i said, it is not a good investment in manhours. ...

Comment: Even more, if the data is simulated....

Comment: In the odd case there is no sample time and no owner of the data and nothing else, the procedure indicated is quite correct, and the best choice under all those bad luck events... After that, if you take an average of the elapsed time calculated sample by sample, you could finally argue if there is or isnt a regular sampling time, or in the best case, obtain an estimate for it....